# What's the difference between the word "convention" and "standard"?

Tags: meaning

I know this is a basic question.

"Although this technique is the standard, it is not the convention."

In this sentence, I would interpret the word, "standard", as something that is accepted by a certain group and offers a high quality result when used, and the word, "convention", as used by everybody.

All in all, I would interpret this sentence as,

"Although this gives high quality result, it is not used by everybody."

Am I in the right course?

Another example from me would be the used of mathematical symbols. Mathematicians use it because it is the "convention". It doesn't seem using the "well known mathematical symbols" is the standard though.

When I try to use my interpretation of the word, "standard", which just means, "gives high quality result", I doubt that using mathematical symbols doesn't gives any of it (high quality result).

Comment: You need to give the source of, and context for, your example: "Although this technique is the standard, it is not the convention." does not seem very idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 1):

First, some definitions:

> **standard** *noun*
> 2 Something used as a measure, norm, or model in comparative evaluations.
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/standard)
>
> **convention** *noun*
> 1 A way in which something is usually done.
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/convention)

While there is a lot of overlap in both definition and usage, the distinction being drawn is between externally-formalised techniques (e.g. by [standards organisations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standards_organization)) and internally-adopted ones (the conventions).